# Printing out the List

Tags: python, list

How would I print out the list?

```
def main():
    fileName = input("Please input name of file to read: ")
    fileOpen = open(fileName)
    lineList = fileOpen.readlines()
    print("Hercules' Strategy:", lineList[len(lineList)-3].strip())
    print("Initial Hydra heads:",lineList[len(lineList)- 2].strip())
    print("Hydra growth period:", lineList[len(lineList)-1].strip())

main()
```

Textfile:

```
smallest
8 7 3
10
```

Current Output:

```
Hercules' Strategy: smallest
Initial Hydra heads: 8 7 3
Hydra growth period: 10
```

The output I am trying to get is that that:

```
Hercules' Strategy: smallest
Initial Hydra heads: [8, 7, 3]
Hydra growth period: 10
```

Comment: This not a list I think. it's just a string. If you just want the bracket, why not `print '[' + you_string + ']'`

Comment: @gongzhitaao Yeah exactly. That is my problem right now. I wanted to print out the list, not the string.

Comment: So you actually want to parse the string to a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just split the string and print it as numbers like this

```
print("Initial Hydra heads:",list(map(int, lineList[len(lineList)-2].strip().split())))
```

As Hyperboreus suggested, you can use negative indexing with the list, so the following is the same as the previous line

```
print("Initial Hydra heads:",list(map(int, lineList[-2].strip().split())))
```

Comment: I got this output: `Initial Hydra heads: <map object at 0x104929b10>`

Comment: @user2985771 I think you are using Python 3. Please check my answer now

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, it took a while to accept your post as a answer!

Comment: What is the magic of using `len(lineList)-2` instead of `-2`?

Comment: @Hyperboreus I included your suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the data in a list, you can also join the list into a string like so:

```
joinedList = "[" + ", ".join( lineList[len(lineList)-3] ) + "]"
```

If you aren't actually interested in having the data as a list, you should just process the string into the format you want, as thefourtheye suggests.